# Make inserting image via css after cross browser

Tags: html, image, css, firefox, cross-browser

I'm currently trying to insert some separator image between li elements of menu via css `:after` property:

```
nav ul li:after
{
    content: url('../Content/Images/BorderSeparator.png');
    display: block;
    height: 30px;        
    padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;        
}
```

And this solution works for all latest versions of Chrome, Opera, Safari, except from Firefox.
 How can I fix it for Firefox also?

Update 1:

This is how it supposed to look like

[image]

Problem is somehow relate to `overflow:hidden`, when I remove this attribute FF displays separator, but not in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

In firefox the overflow and the padding are not compatible try to uncomment padding to verify. try to use instead  left top.